# Matching dropdown quantity and calculating total price

Tags: javascript

I want to select the number of person attending and it must be matched with meal quantity.

User must specify whether vegetarian meal or non-vegetarian. A veg meal costs $5 while a non-veg meal cost $10. For example, if there's 3 person attending with 2 vegetarian and 1 non-vegetarian, the total price of meal will be $20 total. Also the meal quantity options must have only 3 person in total. How do I do this in Javascript only?

How do I display the final price also?

```js
function validate() {
  var dn = document.getElementById("dropDN").value;
  return false;
}

function showInput() {
  document.getElementById('displaydn').innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("dropDN").value;
}
```

```html
<form class="myForm" onsubmit="return validate();">
  Number of person attending:
  <select id="dropDN">
    <option value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="One">1</option>
    <option value="Two">2</option>
    <option value="Three">3</option>
    <option value="Four">4</option>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br />Meal Quantity Options: Vegetarian
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="" name="" id="veg">
  <input type="number" max="4" />
  <br /> Non-Vegetarian
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="" name="" id="nonveg">
  <input type="number" max="4" />
  <br />
  <br />

  <br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput()">
  <br>
  <br> Number of person attending: <span id="displaydn"> </span>
  <br />
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you need to know how many people are attending? What's the point of the checkboxes?

Comment: @LeeTaylor The number of person must match with the quantity of meal. The checkboxes are there to choose their meal options. Some are vegetarian and some non-vegetarian

Comment: You could also auto-fill the other meal with the remainder when filling out one input. You could also use a slider with the total as the set-max

Comment: Why don't you just ask for how many vegetarian and non-vegetarian meals are needed? Do people order 0 meals, or 2 or more meals?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I want show the total number of people attending also. That's why. The value should match with the number of meals they select

Comment: @Sugma Please see my answer. Add comments to my answer if you need anything else added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Listen to the `change` event for both `input` controls.
2. When they change, update the respective global variable (either `vegetarian` or `nonVegetarian` and then update the total meals and cost values.

```js
var vegetarian = 0;
var nonVegetarian = 0;
var cost = 0.00;

document.querySelector('#veg').addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
  vegetarian = parseInt(document.querySelector('#veg').value, 10);
  
  if(vegetarian + nonVegetarian > 4) // Make sure we never have more than 4 customers
  {
    nonVegetarian--;
    document.querySelector('#nonveg').value = nonVegetarian;
  }
    
  update();
});

document.querySelector('#nonveg').addEventListener('change', function(e)
{
  nonVegetarian = parseInt(document.querySelector('#nonveg').value, 10);
  if(vegetarian + nonVegetarian > 4) // Make sure we never have more than 4 customers
  {
    vegetarian--;
    document.querySelector('#veg').value = vegetarian;
  }
  update();
});

var update = function()
{
  document.querySelector('#attending').innerText = vegetarian + nonVegetarian;
  document.querySelector('#cost').innerText = (vegetarian*5) + (nonVegetarian *10);
};

update();
```

```html
<form class="myForm" onsubmit="return validate();">
  Meal Quantity Options: Vegetarian
  <input id="veg" type="number" min="0" max="4" value="0" /><br /> 
  Non-Vegetarian
  
  <input id="nonveg" type="number" min="0" max="4" value="0" /><br />
  <br />

  <br> Number of people attending: <span id="attending"></span>
  <br> Cost : $<span id="cost"></span>
  <br />
</form>
```

Comment: This works good however is there a way I can set it so that the number of people attending is maximum 4 person only? Thank you very much